# Android - How to make textfields center alligned for different android devices

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working on android application.I am newbie in android app development. 
I get to test the app for few android devices. But the layout looks different for different devices. i have created screen shots for reference.[image: Thes screen shot shows perfect layout for app design]

[image: There are some design issues with layout for Larger resolution devices]

CODE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bgcopy"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    style="@style/TitleBar" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bround1"
        android:text="@string/back"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        style="@style/TitleBarText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/testApp"
        android:textSize="16dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bround1"
        android:text="@string/home"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1.5dp"
    android:background="@color/Black" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/blackroundshape" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restrictions"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blackroundshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blackroundshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/locations"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/blackroundshape"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="@string/news"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"        
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
    android:gravity="center"  
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/reserve"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="58dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/reserve"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/favorite"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="58dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/favorite"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/share"
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="58dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/backbutton"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="@string/share"
        android:textColor="@color/White"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="504dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_margin="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/round_transperent2" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_ptr_rotate" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/couponText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:typeface="serif" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/image"
            android:layout_below="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:text="@string/save"
            android:textColor="@color/mightyBlue"
            android:textSize="19sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/upto_textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:text="@string/upto"
            android:textColor="@color/Gray" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amountDetails"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/save_textView2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
            android:text="@string/amount"
            android:textColor="@color/mightyBlue"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/amountDetails"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/couponText"
            android:text="Expires on:"
            android:textColor="@color/Black"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/expitydate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/amountDetails"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView5"
            android:maxLength="10"                
            android:textColor="@color/Black" 
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RemainingDays_textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:text="Remaning Days"
        android:textColor="@color/mightyBlue" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/RemainingDays_textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/redeem"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/redeemnow"
        android:textColor="@color/Red"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/YES"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_ball"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="YES"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/No"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/YES"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/YES"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginRight="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/yellow_ball"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="NO"
        android:textColor="@color/Black"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

2nd screen shot shows the issue. I have completed the functional aspect of the app but unable to submit app due to this issue. Any help will be appriciated.

Thank You!!!

Comment: Can you post some of your XML files? to fix the bar, id suggest a linear layout and to fix the black space id suggest a relative layout. If you post your code I can help tell what exactly to change

Comment: I have edited the question and added the XML in it.

Answer (score 1):

The containing LinearLayout should have gravity = center to center the TextView children `and android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` (I see you have a RelativeLayout as a parent container):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restrictions"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Locations"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="news"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/navBar"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restrictions"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Locations"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="news"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/restrictions"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="Details"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/locations"
        android:layout_width="115dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginRight="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Locations"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/news"
        android:layout_width="128dip"
        android:layout_height="54dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0.5dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:text="news"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: I updated my answer with a complete layout of what i understood you were looking for. It's not the same aesthetics but the mechanism it there

Comment: Thank you.. textview are now aligned..but the black gap in the bottom is still there..:(

Comment: If your topmost container is a RelativeLayout with `android:layout_height="match_parent"` and the bottom bar LinearLayout is a direct child of it and has `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` then it should be exactly as shown in the picture.

Comment: RelativeLayout height is "Fill_Parent" and bottom bar LinearLayout has android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: You have to post your complete layout, and not just parts of it. I suspect that your bottom LinearLayout is not a direct child of the topmost RelativeLayout but without looking at the complete hierarchy I'm just guessing.

Comment: Again, it's missing the tomost layout the one that contains everything else... the one that has the `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` deceleration. Your layout is obviously created using the Graphical Layout builder tool. You need to (as a principle) flatten your hierarchy by removing some ViewGroups (e.g. you have a RelativeLayout inside another RelativeLayout) and please name your containers so they make sense.. linearLayout1 isn't very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Have added different layouts for different screen sizes?

Refer : http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

For Different screen size, The following is a list of resource directories in an application that provides different layout designs for different screen sizes and different bitmap drawables for small, medium, high, and extra high density screens.

```
res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

The following code in the Manifest supports all dpis.

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
          android:normalScreens="true" 
          android:largeScreens="true"
          android:xlargeScreens="true"
          android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

using layout_weight attribute you can bring this exactly.

Comment: i have set layout:weight=2  for all textviews. but it does not work.

Comment: I would use layout:weight=1

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure you have the correct hierarchy with the proper layouts wrapping other layouts. For the 2nd bar from the top with "Reserve, Favorite, Share" use a Linear Layout with weights of 1 on the text views and be sure that the TV's width = 0dp. Then create the bottom bar with "Details, Location, News" and align that to the bottom. Then have the middle white part as a layout with attributes layout_below="topbar" and layout_above="bottombar"

Here's some sudo code to give you an idea

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <!-- Top Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        andorid:name="@+id/nav_bar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width=... />

    <!--  Second to Top Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:name="@+id/reserve_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/nav_bar"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Very Bottom Bar -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:name="@+id/details_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            ... />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- Body of the layout below 2nd bar and above bottom bar-->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:name="@+id/body_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/reserve_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/detail_bar" >

        <RelativeLayout>
            android:stuff="..."
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think the problem is that you are have align_bottom attributes on some things that shouldn't be there. Those are override the alignParentBottom